# suppressing the v-html wrapping tag

Tags: vue.js

Consider the following code. I want to toggle an excerpt and description. The code directly below does that, but it means having the `<a>` outside of the article, and I would prefer it inside.

```
<article v-if="!toggle" v-html="item.excerpt"></article>
<a href="#" v-if="!toggle" @click.prevent="toggle = 1">Read more...</a>

<article v-if="toggle" v-html="item.description"></article>
<a href="#" v-if="toggle" @click.prevent="toggle = 0">Show less...</a>
```

It could be rewritten as

```
<article v-if="!toggle">
  <span v-html="item.excerpt"></span>
  <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle = 1">Read more...</a>
</article>

<article v-if="toggle">
  <span v-html="item.description"></span>
  <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle = 0">Show less...</a>
</article>
```

But that would mean the excerpt/description is wrapped with a `<span>`. Is there a way to use the `v-html` directive and not output the wrapping tag?

Comment: Does it work to use `template` like https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt ?

Comment: Not sure I would go for a template on this as its just two elements. I was just hoping to not output the wrapping tag, like you can do with slots

Comment: That's what Vue handles the template tag for: to allow you to put bindings on something that will not have a tag in the generated HTML.

Comment: that helps with having one `v-if` statement but not the extra tag. I would still end up with the `<a>` outside of the `<article>`

Answer (score 9):

What I would *like* to do is (**does not work**)

```
  <article v-if="toggle">
    <template v-html="item.description"></template>
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle = 0">Show less...</a>
  </article>
```

but it turns out that using a `template` this way only works with control-flow directives (`v-for` and `v-if`). So I wondered if I could sneak around it by adding a control-flow directive to the `template` tag (**also does not work**)

```
  <article v-if="toggle">
    <template v-if="toggle" v-html="item.description"></template>
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle = 0">Show less...</a>
  </article>
```

or by putting the `v-html` on the `article` tag (**of course not**)

```
  <article v-if="toggle" v-html="item.description">
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle = 0">Show less...</a>
  </article>
```

That left me with two options I knew would work:

(1) Use a tag. A slight improvement over using a `span` is using a custom tag, which the browser is guaranteed not to default-style in any way. The tag is included in the HTML, but does not affect the display compared to having bare HTML.

```
 <article v-if="toggle">
    <non-styled v-html="item.description"></non-styled>
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle = 0">Show less...</a>
  </article>
```

(2) Use a custom directive. Although `v-html` replaces the entire innerHTML of its element, you can certainly write a directive to insert its value at the beginning (or end) of its element and not remove everything else.

```
  <article v-if="toggle" v-start-with-html="item.description">
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle = 0">Show less...</a>
  </article>
```

It's a very straightforward command, although I'm sure my implementation is under-thought-out in terms of dealing with node updates.

```
  directives: {
    startWithHtml: {
      inserted(el, binding) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', binding.value);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with component slots here is a small (Vue 3)  component based on [Roy J's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392102/roy-j) [directive idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731927/suppressing-the-v-html-wrapping-tag/69795458#45736581)

**Please note!** createContextualFragment allows script execution - why you may want to add some sort of sanitation step :)

```js
const {
  createApp,
  defineComponent
} = Vue


//
//  v-html component 
//
const VHtml = defineComponent({
  name: 'VHtml',
  props: {
    html: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  directives: {
    swap: {
      mounted(el, binding) {

        // createContextualFragment allows script execution 
        // why you would probably want to sanitize the html
        // e.g. using https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify 
        let safe = DOMPurify.sanitize(binding.value)

        let frag = document.createRange()
          .createContextualFragment(safe)
        el.replaceWith(frag)
      }
    }
  },
  template: `<div v-swap="html"></div>`
})





//
//  Use Example 
//
const VueComp = defineComponent({
  template: `
    <h2>A Component</h2>
    <slot />
  `
})

const VueApp = defineComponent({
  components: {
    VueComp
  },
  setup() {
    const list = [
      '<h3>Some HTML</h3>',
      '<p>Paragraph lorem</p>',
      'No tag ipsum',
      '<hr />',
      '<img src=evil onerror=alert(1)//> Evil XSS attempt' 
    ]
    return {
      list
    }
  },
  template: `
    <h1>The App</h1>
    <VueComp>
      <v-html :html="item" v-for="item in list" />
    </VueComp>              
   `
})


const app = createApp(VueApp)
app.component('v-html', VHtml)
app.mount('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dompurify@2"></script>
```